# Insert text in the middle of column names in R

Tags: r, string, text, gsub

I would like to insert a string `"_2010_"` after the `.` in the `colnames` of a `data.frame`

```
data("iris")

> names(iris)
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"
```

Desired **output**:

```
[1] "Sepal._2010_Length" "Sepal._2010_Width"  "Petal._2010_Length" "Petal._2010_Width"  "Species"
```

help ?

**EDIT:**
related question: now how to insert the string `"_2010_"` **before** the `.` ?

```
[1] "Sepal_2010_.Length" "Sepal_2010_.Width"  "Petal_2010_.Length" "Petal_2010_.Width"  "Species"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` and on the `names` of 'iris' which has a `.` (by subsetting with `grep`).  Here, we use capture groups (`(...)`) and replace with the backreferences (`\\1`) along with the newly added substrings (`_2010_`).

```
i1 <- grep("[.]", names(iris))
name(iris)[i1] <- sub("([^.]+.)(.*)", "\\1_2010_\\2", names(iris)[i1])
```

---

Or using a single capture group where we match a dot (`.\\`) followed by characters until the end of the string in a capture group.  Replace it with a dot followed by the substring and the backreference.

```
sub("\\.(.*)", "._2010_\\1", names(iris))
#[1] "Sepal._2010_Length" "Sepal._2010_Width"  "Petal._2010_Length"
#[4] "Petal._2010_Width"  "Species"
```

If we need the string before the `.` just change the order of placement of strings in the replacement

```
sub("\\.(.*)", "_2010_.\\1", names(iris))
#[1] "Sepal_2010_.Length" "Sepal_2010_.Width"  "Petal_2010_.Length"
#[4] "Petal_2010_.Width"  "Species"
```

Comment: Thanls @akrun, that's really helpful. How would the answer change if I wanted to include the string **before** the `.` ?

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `strsplit` and `paste`:

```
sapply(strsplit(names(iris), "\\."), paste, collapse = "_2010_")
[1] "Sepal_2010_Length" "Sepal_2010_Width"  "Petal_2010_Length" "Petal_2010_Width"  "Species"
```

You may also put an extra dot wherever you prefer:

```
sapply(strsplit(names(iris), "\\."), paste, collapse = "._2010_")
[1] "Sepal._2010_Length" "Sepal._2010_Width"  "Petal._2010_Length" "Petal._2010_Width"  "Species"

sapply(strsplit(names(iris), "\\."), paste, collapse = "_2010_.")
[1] "Sepal_2010_.Length" "Sepal_2010_.Width"  "Petal_2010_.Length" "Petal_2010_.Width"  "Species"
```

Comment: That's really helpful, specially because the syntax of `strsplit` looks a bit more intuitive than `sub`

Answer (score 1):

The function `str_replace` in the package `stringr` is ideal for this problem, and very easy to use.

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(names(iris), "\\.", "_2010_.")
#[1] "Sepal_2010_.Length" "Sepal_2010_.Width"  "Petal_2010_.Length" 
#[4] "Petal_2010_.Width"  "Species"
```

If you want `.` before the first `_`, just put `"._2010_"` in your syntax for `str_replace`. We use `\\.` and not just `.` because the dot already has meaning and we need to escape that if we want to match it specifically (http://regexone.com/lesson/wildcards_dot).